# Опечатка: Вопрос был удаленО

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Заметил ещё одну опечатку в локализации:

> Вопрос был удален**о** — новые ответы приниматься не будут.

Такое сообщение появилось, пока писал сообщение, когда хотел ответить на вопрос. Видимо, автор нашёл решение сам и удалил вопрос.

P.S. Опять система не пропускает короткое сообщение. Может, о таких небольших замеченных ошибках просто писать в чате?

Comment: Неа, в чат точно не нужно. Обманите систему, потом можно удалить лишний текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Transifex есть [две похожих строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261889?qt=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82).

1. Показывается в верхней части экрана.

   > Вопрос был $message$ — новые ответы приниматься не будут.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Показывается рядом с кнопкой

> Вопрос был удален; новые ответы приниматься не будут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут исправил **е** на **ё**.

В случае данного вопроса использовалась первая строка. Единственная подходящая на роль `$message$` строка это ([Tx:1943](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263634?key=da602f0b162fccbf6b150cfcfc7a7379)):

> deleted
>   удалено

Проверил другие сообщения на удаленных объектах - вроде бы больше нигде эта строка не используется. Поэтому исправляю в Transifex на "удалён".